Remix + Apollo SSR warning: Detected multiple renderers concurrently rendering the same context provider
I have this entry.server.tsx
import type { AppLoadContext, EntryContext } from "@remix-run/cloudflare";
import { RemixServer } from "@remix-run/react";
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client/index.js";
import { getDataFromTree } from "@apollo/client/react/ssr/index.js";

import { createGraphqlClientServer } from "./graphql/apollo.server";
import { ApolloStateContext } from "./graphql/apolloStateContext";

export default async function handleRequest(
  request: Request,
  responseStatusCode: number,
  responseHeaders: Headers,
  remixContext: EntryContext,
  // This is ignored so we can keep it in the template for visibility.  Feel
  // free to delete this parameter in your app if you're not using it!
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  loadContext: AppLoadContext
) {
  let gqlClient = createGraphqlClientServer(loadContext)

  let app = (
    <ApolloProvider client={gqlClient}>
      <RemixServer context={remixContext} url={request.url} />
    </ApolloProvider>
  )

  await getDataFromTree(app)
  let gqlState = gqlClient.extract()

  app = (
    <ApolloStateContext.Provider value={gqlState}>
      {app}
    </ApolloStateContext.Provider>
  )

  let html = renderToString(
    app,
  );


  responseHeaders.set("Content-Type", "text/html");
  return new Response(html, {
    headers: responseHeaders,
    status: responseStatusCode,
  });
}

When I npm run dev and visit the app in the browser, I get this warning in the server terminal:
Warning: Detected multiple renderers concurrently rendering the same context provider. This is currently unsupported.
    at ApolloProvider (file:///home/vlady/code/apollo-relay-pagination-bug/node_modules/@apollo/client/react/context/ApolloProvider.js:6:21)
Warning: Detected multiple renderers concurrently rendering the same context provider. This is currently unsupported.
    at RemixServer (/home/vlady/code/apollo-relay-pagination-bug/node_modules/@remix-run/react/dist/server.js:48:3)
    at ApolloProvider (file:///home/vlady/code/apollo-relay-pagination-bug/node_modules/@apollo/client/react/context/ApolloProvider.js:6:21)
Warning: Detected multiple renderers concurrently rendering the same context provider. This is currently unsupported.
    at StaticRouterProvider (/home/vlady/code/apollo-relay-pagination-bug/node_modules/react-router-dom/server.js:67:3)
    at RemixErrorBoundary (/home/vlady/code/apollo-relay-pagination-bug/node_modules/@remix-run/react/dist/errorBoundaries.js:41:5)
    at RemixServer (/home/vlady/code/apollo-relay-pagination-bug/node_modules/@remix-run/react/dist/server.js:48:3)
    at ApolloProvider (file:///home/vlady/code/apollo-relay-pagination-bug/node_modules/@apollo/client/react/context/ApolloProvider.js:6:21)

How do I fix this? It seems to go away when I comment out getDataFromTree, but I want to use it for server-side rendering of the data.
// await getDataFromTree(app)

Full reproduction repo: https://github.com/vladinator1000/remix-apollo-ssr-pagination
Related links from other people having similar problems:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/37424
https://github.com/adamsoffer/next-apollo/issues/119
https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/22797

